Does concept of Fallen Deities are occur in Hinduism?
I have recently learned that Supreme Yaskin from the movie "Kalki 2898 AD" is a fallen god. It is interesting fact and i want to know about it, so my question is:-
Does our Hinduism occur the fallen Deities? If yes, which scriptures mention them?

The concept of 'fallen deity' in the cinema is most likely derived from the notion of fallen angels in Abrahamic religions. Such a concept isn't found in Hinduism. The thing which gets nearest to it is deities cursed to be born as humans. A good example is Yama being cursed by Mandavya to be born as Vidura.

Hmm.. It make sense.
